# Keras ModelCheckpoint: can save_freq/period change dynamically?

Tags: python, keras, model, checkpoint

*I wonder if there is a way to change `save_freq`/`period` parameter in Keras ModelCheckpoint. What I would like to do is save after every epoch BUT start saving after the 10th epoch, not before. So I want ModelCheckpoint to be "inactive" for the first 10 epochs and after the 10th epoch become "active" with `save_freq='epoch'`.*

*Can something like that be implemented or it's impossible?*

*I tried `save_freq=batch_size if epoch<10 else 'epoch'` but, as expected, `epoch` variable was unknown. Is there a "local" variable in ModelCheckpoint for the epochs?*

**UPDATE**: Instead of trying to dynamically change `save_freq` parameter, I tried to do two different trainings, one after the other. The first training lasts 10 epochs and saves the trained model at the last (10th) epoch, and the second lasts 110 epochs and saves the model after each epoch.

My question is: do I have to load the saved model after the 1st training or I can continue immediately to the 2nd training, just like in the code below?

```py
# [...]

batch_size = 32

epochs0    = 10
epochs     = 110


callbacks0 = [
    keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        resuts_dir+'model0/',
        monitor='val_loss',
        verbose=1,
        save_best_only=False,
        save_weights_only=False,
        save_freq=batch_size*epochs0)
    ]
callbacks  = [
    keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        resuts_dir+'model/',
        monitor='val_loss',
        verbose=1,
        save_best_only=True,
        save_weights_only=False,
        save_freq='epoch'),
    keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
        monitor='val_loss',
        min_delta=0,
        patience=20,
        verbose=1,
        mode='auto')
    ]

# [...]

training_history0 = model.fit(train_gen, epochs=epochs0, validation_data=val_gen, callbacks=callbacks0, verbose=1)
training_history  = model.fit(train_gen, epochs=epochs,  validation_data=val_gen, callbacks=callbacks,  verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand your update, but to answer the question *"can I save checkpoints only after epoch 10?"*, the answer is yes. You can create a class that inherits from the class `ModelCheckpoint` and modify the class method `on_epoch_end`, as follows:

```
class CustomCheckpoint(tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint):
    def __init__(self, filepath, monitor, verbose, save_best_only, 
                 save_weights_only, min_epochs, save_freq):
        self.min_epochs = min_epochs
        super().__init__(filepath=filepath, 
                         monitor=monitor,
                         verbose=verbose,
                         save_best_only=save_best_only,
                         save_weights_only=save_weights_only
                         save_freq=save_freq)
    
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        if self.save_freq == 'epoch':
            if (epoch+1) >= self.min_epochs:
                self._save_model(epoch=epoch, logs=logs)
```

And then call an instance of this class on your model.fit:

```
MIN_EPOCHS = 10
custom_callback = CustomCheckpoint(filepath="checkpoint_e{epoch:02d}", # this filepath includes the epoch name
                                   min_epochs=MIN_EPOCHS, 
                                   monitor='val_loss',
                                   verbose=1,
                                   save_best_only=False,
                                   save_weights_only=False,
                                   save_freq='epoch')

model.fit(..., callbacks=[custom_callback])
```

Comment: The source code also includes this piece of code. `self.epochs_since_last_save += 1` Is this needed as well?